# Nearest neighbor search algorithm of quantization

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I'm doing some research on Nearest Neighbor Search of quantization, where running speed is very important. As I've just started using Python, I wonder if the following code for multi-processes can be further optimized to obtain faster running speed.

```
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def search_neighbors(self, C, queries, S_ind):
    """
    It will return the top k neighbors about queries, which will be saved by a matrix.
    
    C is codebook in the quantization algorithm, in this case, it's set to 1 dimension ndarray

    The algorithm has compressed each data into M integers.
    S_ind is the compressed representation of used dataset. Its shape is (num, M), where num is the numbers of used dataset.
    """

    n = queries.shape[0]
    topk = 512
    Neighbor_Matrix = np.zeros((n,topk),dtype=int)
    result = Parallel(n_jobs = 5)(delayed(self.search_neightbor)(C,S_ind,q,top_k=topk) for q in queries)
    for i in range(n):
        Neighbor_Matrix[i] = result[i]        
    return Neighbor_Matrix


def search_neightbor(self, C, S_ind, query, top_k=64):
    '''        
    It will return the top k neighbors about a query.       
    '''
    
    # M,Ks are the parameters of the quantization algorithm,which are some integers
    M = self.M 
    Ks = self.Ks

    # Ds = (the dimension of the used data) / M.
    Ds = self.Ds
    
    Table = np.zeros((M, Ks))
    for i in range(M):
        query_sub = query[i * Ds:(i + 1) * Ds]
        C_i = C[i * Ks * Ds:(i + 1) * Ks * Ds]
        codebook_i = C_i.reshape(Ds, Ks, order="F")
        Table[i] = query_sub.T @ codebook_i

    i1 = np.arange(M)
    quantization_inner = np.sum(Table[i1, S_ind[..., i1]], axis=1) 

    ind = np.argpartition(quantization_inner, -top_k)[-top_k:]
    return ind[np.argsort(quantization_inner[ind])]
```

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestion.

Comment: Maybe using a slice instead of the loop     `for i in range(n):
        Neighbor_Matrix[i] = result[i]` could be faster